# What is the difference between a regular language defined by DFA vs NFA?

Tags: automata, regular-language, finite-automata

Is there any difference between regular language defined by DFA vs NFA?

Comment: No. For every NFA there's an equivalent DFA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, for every regular language defined by an NFA there is a DFA defining the same language. This is shown by the [Powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction). The other direction is trivial as every DFA is also a NFA.